# How to align div to bottom of the page, not bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to align a div to the bottom of the PAGE, not to the bottom of the screen. When I do this:

```
#contact-block{
position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; left: 0; 
}
```

, the div is placed in the bottom area of the screen. When my page is long, I have to scroll down and the div which should have been at the bottom, floats somewhere in the middle.

There might be a simple solution to this, but I'm just not seeing it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="left">
<div id="submenu"> <span class="menutitle">Services</span>
  <ul> 
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="contact-block">
 <span class="contacttitle">Contact</span></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I've also added a little image to illustrate what I mean:
[image]

The red div is the contact div.

**Edit:
I've found a solution with jQuery and CSS. This might not be the best solution, but hey, it works.**

jQuery:

```
var offset= $(document).height()-$("#contact-block").height()- $("#footer").height()-60;
$("#contact-block").css("top", offset);
$("#contact-block").css("left", $("#wrapper").position().left);
```

CSS:

```
#contact-block {
position : absolute;
width:216px;
height:100px;
background:url(../img/contact-bg.jpg) repeat-x #5c5c5c;
}
```

Comment: So, why don't you just put it on the bottom of html ?

Comment: it's a block on the left of the content, below the menu, in the same div of the menu. The menu is aligned to the top, and the contact block should be aligned to the bottom.

Comment: Properly answering this question would require your HTML + CSS, but I assume you have this element positioned relative to something you don't intend for it to be.

Comment: Why don't you share your answer with everyone else?

Comment: What do you mean? I've edited my question with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The position of your `absolute` positioned element depends on the first ancestor-element, which is not positioned `static` ( which is the default, so you have to explicitely set it to `relative`(or `absolute`) ).

So, make sure, your enclosing `#left` container has 100% document-heigth and `position:relative`, and everything is well.

Answer (score 2):

You could absolute-position the your `div`s in place. This technique requires a `#wrapper` element, which I'm not a fan of, but hey, you gotta do watcha gotta do.

In this example I removed the `#left` `div` entirely as it was only required for layout purposed and is no longer necessary.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="submenu">This is services</div>
    <div id="contact-block">This is contact</div>
    <div id="content">This is content</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 960px; 
}

#submenu { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 320px; 
    height: 320px; 
}

#contact-block { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 320px; 
    height: 160px; 
}

#content { 
    position: relative; 
    left: 320px; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 640px; 
    height: 640px; 
}

//#content position is relative for the #wrapper to stretch. 
//The left property is equal to the width of the #submenu or #contact-block element
```

A good point of this technique is that it gives you cleaner HTML. I believe it will be easier to make a mobile version of your version if the need arise.

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/JYq7S/)

**Additional thought:**
The `#wrapper` element could easily be removed in favor of you `body` element, which is a great step towards semantic HTML. [**Check this out!**](http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/using-the-body-element-as-a-wrapper/)

Comment: I was trying to use body as the wrapper element - what I didn't realise was that because my content was larger than the window I needed position:relative on the body or by default an absolutely positioned element is relative to the window!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the red div inside the right long div and at the end of it. Then use `position: relative` and negative left margins on the red div to push it out to the left. This way, as your right div expands, your red div always stays at the bottom of it.