# How can I position a div at the very bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, absolute

I have a simple div `<div id="bottom"></div>` that I want to position at the very bottom of the page. If I do

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0%;
```

then it positions itself at the bottom of the visible portion of the page, not the actual bottom. And if I do

```
position: relative;
bottom: 0%;
```

it just stays in its default location. How can I place it at the very bottom?

Comment: you want it always *sticking* to the bottom?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750265/how-to-align-div-to-bottom-of-the-page-not-bottom-of-the-screen

Comment: I want it at the very bottom of the full page. So if the page is 5000px tall for example, it should be 5000px from the top of the page, regardless of what part of the page I'm viewing.

Comment: @t.niese By visible portion, I mean what I can see on my screen. If I scroll down 50 pixels, then the visible portion will start 50 pixels down from the top of the page. By the actual bottom, I mean the very lowest point it is possible to see. So if I scroll down as far as I can go, then the bottom of my screen will show the 'actual bottom'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4zbah6de/1/)

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- Header start -->
        <h1>How to keep footers at the bottom of the page (CSS demo)</h1>
        <!-- Header end -->
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <!-- Body start -->
        <p>In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal.</p>
        <!-- Body end -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Footer start -->
        <p><strong>Footer</strong> (always at the bottom).</p>
        <!-- Footer end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ff0;
    padding:10px;
}
#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}
/* other non-essential CSS */
 #header p, #header h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
}
#footer p {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Note : If your body content is long enough your footer will be at the bottom of the page. If content is short enough it will stick at the bottom of screen.

Comment: That code still just places my footer at the bottom of the screen, not the page. I can't imagine why it would work on jsfiddle but not on my application..

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stick to the bottom of the browser's window, you need to use `position: fixed`.

Answer (score -1):

With your code, the div appears at the bottom of the body, but the problem is that body not uses all the height of the screen. To solve this, you have to change 'html' and 'body' entities to use all the height.

I think these CSS styles can help:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

    /* Following styles let see the div to check it works */
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #036;
}
```

The mandatory styles for #footer to make it appear on bottom are 'position: absolute' and 'bottom: 0'. The other properties can be modified with any value you want.

Comment: That's weird, now the footer is a couple pixels below the bottom of my screen, but it's still far from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Does that work for you? When I run the jsfiddle, the footer is placed on the bottom of the screen, but then when I scroll down, the footer moves up with the rest of the page.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/carlosdurannet/no3gqmku/) ;)

Comment: Is it possible to fix the footer to the bottom of the body, not the visible screen? So initially you wouldn't be able to see it, but as you scroll down, it would eventually be revealed at the very bottom?

Comment: So I think the example of @4dgaurav is the best solution